# Probability of a family having 3 girls and then a boy?

Tags: probability

Helping my daughter with a science fair project.

We are a family with four kids, three girls and then a boy.

What is the probability of a family having four kids and the first three are girls and then a boy?  So... want probability of four kids in that gender order - girl, girl, girl and then boy.

Thank you!

Comment: Well I'd assume just (1/2)^4 = 1/16

Comment: i thought we'd proved prob(girl)=0.51?

Comment: The answer is probably society-dependent. Whether people choose to have another child after say the second or third could depend on the sex distribution of the first couple of children.

Comment: Oh, I never thought of it that way André.

Comment: André raises another question, how many kids would one expect to need to have to get one of each gender?

Answer (score 1):

The probabability of any combination in which the order is given is $\frac{1}{16}$.

We must have the events  $G,G,G,B$ in that order where the probability of each one is $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus the probability is:

$\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: Thank you!  So the probability is the same regardless if we are testing for one boy at any point vs. the boy being last?

Answer (score 0):

We know that the probability of having a boy is $\frac{1}{2}$, and the same applies for having a girl.

Because the question asks for having 3 girls and then a boy in that specific order, we would have a probability of $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{16}$ of that happening.

However, if order didn't matter, then using binomial distribution, the probability would be $\frac{4}{2^4}=\frac{1}{4}$ of having 3 girls and a boy.